# Window scroll not working properly in Mozilla latest version?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, jquery-events

```
(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()){ function() }
```

I am using this code for scroll window its working  fine in Mozilla previous version but in new version when this function execute window shows blank for a few seconds. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This code is incomplete … is it supposed to be a conditional (`if`)? Is `function` the function keyword or a user defined function?

Comment: Mozilla hasn't been maintained since 2006. Why are you supporting it? Or did you mean Firefox? Also, please define "latest version" and "previous version". We don't know what you had installed, and this question will be archived so it would be useful to be able to know which versions it is talking about without looking up the history of releases for the browser.