# window scroll not working properlt in mozila latest version?

Tags: javascript

i am using firefox 10.0.2 and the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() -  jQuery(window).height()){
        load_more();
            }
        });
    });
```

using for window scrool it execute successfully but during execution time my window dip(means show black screen) what is the problem its working fine in privious version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window scroll not working properly in mozila latest version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357854/window-scroll-not-working-properly-in-mozila-latest-version)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. If you need to include more details, edit the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

I concur I see this will lock up any website with jQuery on it when ran in Firefox 10.0.2 (Mac):

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
   alert(1);
});
```